# TableViewCell need manual Scroll to update

Tags: ios, iphone

Everything works fine but , it shows only two data of the first two rows, but it actually have 10 rows data.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(fullData==nil){

        return 2;

    }else{
        return [fulldata count];
    }
}
```

but when i scroll the table view up down it update the tableview cells with rest of the values like all (10 rows data).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        return cell;

    }



    NSDictionary *items=nil;


    NSArray *title;
    NSArray *image;

    for(int i=0;i<[fullData count];i++){

        items=[fullData objectAtIndex:i];

        title=[items objectForKey:@"name"];
        [name addObject:title];

        title = [items objectForKey:@“time”];
        [time addObject:title];

        title = [items objectForKey:@“life_result”];
        [life_result addObject:title];

        image=[items objectForKey:@“achievments”];
        [achievments addObject:image];

    }


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    


    cell.nameLabel.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.segment_name.text=[time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text=[life_result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    //For Image
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[achievments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (data) {

            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
    }];

        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    });

    return cell;
}
```

I want to fix this and want to show the full row data , can anyone please suggest me the way to do the work.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: keep only `return [fulldata count];` remove other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the cell before assigning the values.Once a function hits  return statement function execution stops there.Remove `return cell;` inside the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of considerations you have to make here.

You have to understand that the delegate and datasource methods of UITableView will be called as soon as any undisplayed cell becomes visible. That means that when at some point in your application *fulldata* will be initialized, it will return it's count. And that is probably why all of the cells (instead of 2) will be displayed at some point.

Set some breakpoints in those lines and test when fulldata is not nil anymore.

Also, as kaar3k points out, you are returning a cell for the instance in which no cell could be dequeued (read: in the beginning).
Also, I suggest to remove the GC dispatch call, you are most likely already in the main thread.

Asynchronously setting the image inside cellForRow is a bad idea as well...